How to create deep nested queries in prisma
I am working on generating a specific set of data using prisma and postgresql but I'm struggling with the prisma query to generate this output:
[
    {
        title: "Freestyle Fem",
        scorecardId: 1,
        presentations: [
            {
                title: "Eliza LoPresti",
                status: "EVALUATED",
                criterias: [
                    {
                        name: "Scene",
                        ponderation: 25,
                        scores: [
                            {
                                judge: {
                                    image: "",
                                    name: "Bersy",
                                    lastname: "Cortéz"
                                },
                                value: 8
                            },
                            {
                                judge: {
                                    image: "",
                                    name: "Jean",
                                    lastname: "Croissant"
                                },
                                value: 9
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: "Jessica Chastain",
                status: "EVALUATED",
                criterias: [
                    {
                        name: "Scene",
                        ponderation: 25,
                        scores: [
                            {
                                judge: {
                                    image: "",
                                    name: "Bersy",
                                    lastname: "Cortéz"
                                },
                                value: 5
                            },
                            {
                                judge: {
                                    image: "",
                                    name: "Jean",
                                    lastname: "Croissant"
                                },
                                value: 2
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
];

These are the models of the data:
model User {
  id            Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  email         String     @unique
  name          String
  lastname      String
  image         String?
  password      String
  emailVerified DateTime?
  role          UserRole   @default(USER)
  createdAt     DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime   @updatedAt
  criteria      Criteria[]
  score         Score[]
}

model Heat {
  id            Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  scorecardId   Int
  scorecard     Scorecard      @relation(fields: [scorecardId], references: [id])
  title         String
  order         Int
  presentations Presentation[]
}

model Scorecard {
  id              Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  title           String
  rankFrom        Int        @default(0)
  rankTo          Int        @default(100)
  includesPenalty Boolean    @default(true)
  heats           Heat[]
  criterias       Criteria[]
}

model Criteria {
  id               Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name             String
  ponderation      Int
  judges           User[]
  isVisible        Boolean    @default(true)
  isUndrawCriteria Boolean    @default(false)
  undrawPriority   Int?
  scorecardId      Int?
  scorecard        Scorecard? @relation(fields: [scorecardId], references: [id])
  scores           Score[]
}

model Score {
  id             Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  criteriaId     Int
  criteria       Criteria     @relation(fields: [criteriaId], references: [id])
  userId         Int
  judge          User         @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  presentationId Int
  presentation   Presentation @relation(fields: [presentationId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  value          Int
}

model Presentation {
  id            Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  heatId        Int
  heat          Heat               @relation(fields: [heatId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  title         String
  image         String?
  status        PresentationStatus @default(PENDING)
  hasPenalty    Boolean            @default(false)
  penaltyReason String?
  penaltyValue  Int?
  order         Int
  scores        Score[]
}

enum UserRole {
  USER
  ADMIN
}

enum PresentationStatus {
  EVALUATED
  PENDING
  CLAIM
}

I want to retrieve the information using the simplicity of prisma with something like this but I can't get my head around a way to get the desired output. Maybe I should just run a raw query?
The specific problem comes with including the criterias using the heatId from the Heat table (which relates to the scorecard table which relates to the Score table) but I'm not sure how I can connect them with the prisma.findMany function. I'd appreciate any advice.
await prisma.heat.findMany({
        include: {
            presentations: {
                include: {
                    scores: {
                        include: {
                            judge: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

